# Sonoff wired at celling rose UK

Tags: electrical, lighting

There is no way of getting a neutral to the wall switch so:

Could this work?

I know they would not work together and it would be use the wall switch or the sonoff but what would happen if both were in the “on” position, would that cause a problem. Don’t want to blow the house up!!

I’m just thinking this way if it was off at the wall switch the light could still be turned on and off via the sonoff.

[image]

Comment: ... Except you can't put 2 wires under 1 screw on a terminal block like that.   You will need to come up with some 4-void terminal blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonoff make several different products, if this is their "BASIC WiFi Wireless Smart Switch" it has N,L in and N,L out. It presumably connects L in to L out on receipt of a signal from a remote control.

You show the switches wired in parallel, which should work as you describe:

```
s1  s2  lamp
--- --- ----
on  on  on
on  off on
off on  on
off off off
```

It is doubtful the device is designed for use inside a ceiling rose. It may be hard to find space there. The device might be unable to dissipate heat in a confined space. Ideally you'd ask the manufacturer for advice.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer.

I already have several of these around the house wired behind the wall switches where neutral was available, neutral out is not required on them as they just switch the live. I’ve few flashed with Tasmota firmware and use wires going to GPIO pins on the sonoff from the wall switch, a few I’ve got working off custom made button switches using MQTT. They all seem pretty reliable so far. I was just checking the switches both on the “on” position wasn’t going to cause a problem.

Comment: sonoffs should definitely not be getting warm under normal operation switching a modest load like a chandelier; the only current would be the relay's hold current and the ESP's 70ma running from a SMPS.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the switch with one of the Sonoff remotes and set it up to control the light.

This however requires that you use one of the browns as neutral to power the switch (moving wire 2 to the 6,7,8 bundle) which I am not sure is according to code. It is possible you will also need a fuse on that connection.

Comment: Would still need another wire going from the switch up to the light to do the above. This light can be switched from 3 separate wall switches (which will be the normal way it will be used) the sonoff is just there so the light can be remotely turned on if the switches are off.

Comment: That doesn't quite match up with the wiring in the question. But you can replace each switch with a remote.